# Is there an AMI that takes SSH on port 443?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

My question is, put simply

> **Is there any AMI that comes with SSH configured on port 443?**

The main reason why I ask is that, despite working in IT, my company filters all ports but 443 and 80, and requires all my connections to go through an HTTP proxy.

I have connected via SSH before on hosts that accept ssh on port 443, using [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/). A friend of mine is still able to do that, but it involves leaving the office or using a VPN to connect to the amazon instance, changing the line in the SSHD config, and restarting SSH.

Is there an AMI that has that done by default?

Comment: One thing you could try using is AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) which allows port redirection in its configuration. You could redirect (tcp/443) on ELB to (tcp/22) on your instance, then connecting to ELB (tcp/443) will connect you to SSH on your instance. I have just tested this, it does work. ELB is a fairly cheap cost for achieving this without modifying an existing instance. You could also use ELB for an hour at a time to reduce costs, however configuration may be tedious.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal of running sshd on an alternative port like 80 or 443 with a standard EC2 instance, as long as the AMI supports user-data scripts that run when the instance first boots.  Both Amazon Linux and Ubuntu AMIs support this with CloudInit.

For example, you can start an Ubuntu EC2 instance with the following user-data:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
perl -pi -e 's/^#?Port 22$/Port 443/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service sshd restart || service ssh restart
```

and after it boots, you can ssh in to port 443.

Here's an article I wrote a couple years ago describing this method: http://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-ssh-port-80

Comment: Thanks very much! It's not clear what user-data does. So using the standard images that'd work, brilliant!

Comment: What user-data does is dependent on the AMI, but Amazon Linux AMIs and official Ubuntu AMIs all include CloudInit which supports user-data scripts that run on first boot.

Comment: Didn't quite get it to work that way. I did input the user data with touch ~/test but didn't get the file created. Might be something I did wrong. Heh. Wen't home and did it there. :P

Comment: Ohh it did work. :D. It's run as root.